# Using a string variable in a SQL query with Groovy

Tags: groovy

I’m trying to run a sql query with a variable defined elsewhere in the script. When the query is ran against the database it only uses the value `?`, instead of the expected value which is defined as a String earlier in the script.

I'm roughly trying something like:

```
def quickFilterQuery = """
                       SELECT "NAME","QUERY","RAPID_VIEW_ID" from "AO_60DB71_QUICKFILTER" WHERE "QUERY" like '%${CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME}%';
                       """
 log.warn "QF results: $quickFilterQuery"     

...
try {
    StringBuffer slr = new StringBuffer()
    sql.eachRow(quickFilterQuery) { it ->
```

Which results in:

```
WARN [runner.ScriptBindingsManager]: QF results: 
                       SELECT "NAME","QUERY","RAPID_VIEW_ID" from "AO_60DB71_QUICKFILTER" WHERE "QUERY" like '%Ontology%';
                       
WARN [sql.Sql]: Found 0 parameter placeholders but supplied with 1 parameters
WARN [sql.Sql]: Failed to execute: 
                       SELECT "NAME","QUERY","RAPID_VIEW_ID" from "AO_60DB71_QUICKFILTER" WHERE "QUERY" like '%?%';
```

The logging correctly is capturing what the variable *should* be, but the query error seems to not be using the variable correctly.

When I am not using the variable (just the string) it the query works as expected. I assume my formatting is off, but I can't find the issue for the life of me.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61838648/3355860) how to parameterise SQL for JDBC.

Comment: Thanks @ou_ryperd, I'm working through some static type checking errors after adding those changes and will confirm. Is there anything that would make execute different from eachrow in this scenario?

Comment: @ou_ryperd, I can get something similar working with sql.execute, but I'm not having any success with sql.eachRow. Should there be any changes between reading vs writing to the database?

Comment: `sql.execute` is for DML statements (CREATE, ALTER etc.); `sql.insert` for inserts; `sql.query` for a result set and `sql.eachRow/firstRow/rows` for iterable results. More [here](https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V1

Convert quickFilterQuery to string before executing it.
This approach has sql-injection problem - it will not work if CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME contains quote `'` char

```
def CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME = "Ontology"
def quickFilterQuery = """
                       SELECT "NAME","QUERY","RAPID_VIEW_ID" from "AO_60DB71_QUICKFILTER" WHERE "QUERY" like '%${CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME}%';
                       """ as String
sql.eachRow(quickFilterQuery){...}
```

V2

better way to keep quickFilterQuery as GSteing - so, prepared statement (with ?) used to execute and pass query parameters.

you have to remove quotes around ${CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME}

```
def CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME = "%Ontology%"
def quickFilterQuery = """
                       SELECT "NAME","QUERY","RAPID_VIEW_ID" from "AO_60DB71_QUICKFILTER" WHERE "QUERY" like ${CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME};
                       """
sql.eachRow(quickFilterQuery){...}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check- removing the quotes was exactly what I needed.